# water dipole moment

Tags: electrostatics, water, molecules, dipole

I'm working my way through Halliday, Resnick, Walker's chapter on electric fields, and there is a solved sample problem (22-5, 8th ed.) about calculating the charge separation on a water molecule.  The approach the text is using follows:

p = qd = (10e)d

10e was chosen because there are a total of 10 electrons in the water molecule.
My question is that I know that the two hydrogens each have a partial charge of about +0.4, and the oxygen has a partial charge of about -0.8.

Would a better equation look like:

p = qd = (0.8)d

where d is some kind of average distance taking into account the v-geometry of the two H's?  From my understanding of the formulation of a dipole, setting q = 10e as HRW do would imply a geometrical axis of separation of +10e and -10e, which is quite different than the actual charge distribution in a water molecule.

Comment: I do see that accounting for the total # electrons will cause, by inverse proportion, a smaller d of charge separation.  The text's solution yields a d of 3.9 pm, which is much smaller than the length of a covalent bond.  I'm wondering whether that 3.9 pm value has any physical relevance.

Comment: That example is indeed wrong.